# Rails Draper's Decorator caused ArgumentError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, decorator, draper

I set up Draper's Decorator for a Rails project to replace the original helper. I moved the helper code to the Decorator:

```rb
def birthday(date)
  "MinYear#{date.year - 1911} Month#{date.month} Day#{date.day}"
end
```

And add `.decorate` text in View to use it

```
<%= user.decorate.birthday %>
```

However, this will cause an `ArgumentError wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 1)`

```
def birthday(date)
```

If I remove the first date, it will appear a `NoMethodError undefined method 'date' for #<UserDecorator:0x000055570cbafc58>`

```
"MinYear#{date.year - 1911} Month#{date.month} Day#{date.day}"
```

How can I fix these errors?

Comment: Where is `date` defined? It's an attribute on the User model?

Comment: the date defined on the User model  `def age
    Date.today.year - birthday.year
  end`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That `ArgumentError` is raised because you call `birthday` without passing in a `date`.
Doing `<%= user.decorate.birthday(Date.current) %>` will make the error go away.

But, this is probably not what you want since `date` is defined in the `User` model.

The easiest way to decorate something is to use [delegate_all](https://www.rubydoc.info/github/drapergem/draper/Draper%2FDecorator.delegate_all). It will make all methods from the `User` model available in the decorator.

```
class UserDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  delegate_all
  
  def birthday
   "MinYear#{date.year - 1911} Month#{date.month} Day#{date.day}"
  end
end
```

Note that any methods declared in the decorator will override those declared in the model, in your case `birthday`. For example, if you have other methods inside the decorator that call `birthday`, it will use the one from the decorator, not that from the model, which will be available by calling `model.birthday`.

Another approach is to call methods on the [model](https://github.com/drapergem/draper#accessing-the-model) object :

```
class UserDecorator < Draper::Decorator
  def date
    model.date
  end

  def birthday
   "MinYear#{date.year - 1911} Month#{date.month} Day#{date.day}"
  end
end
```

Comment: thank you very much
I use `decorates_association :user` instead of `delegate_all` , is it a good practice? Thank you

Comment: It makes no sense to me why you'd have `decorates_association :user`. How does that decorator which has `birthday` defined, look like?  For a `User` model, usually, a `UserDecorator` should exist. `decorates_association :user` means you have an association called `user` inside the `User` model.

Comment: I am indeed using UserDecorator, and I found that both ways of writing are valid

Comment: I mostly use `delegate_all`. I don't think there's a good or a bad practice but probably one would say if a model has a ton of methods and `delegate_all` is used, it will make all of them available, even if most of them are not used.

Comment: When you have time, please take a look over, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers. Thank you.

Comment: Can I reference Module in UserDecorator? How to do it? Thank you!

Comment: What do you mean by that? Modules can be included in decorators too, there's nothing special about it.